# Check to see if value is in DataFrame series ("The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" error)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to check to see if the value in a DataFrame column is contained in a series in a separate column. I'm receiving the "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

I've researched this, but do not quite understand why I'm receiving this error in this specific instance.

I've tried using both the .contains functions.

A simplified version of the DataFrame structure is as follows:

```
df

index     id       id_list           in_series (desired return column]
1         23       [1,2,34,56,75]    False
2         14       [1,5,14,23,45]    True
3         2        [1,2,4,25,37]     True
4         14       [2,4,34,26,77]    False
5         27       [1,6,19,27,50]    True

a = df['id']
b = df['id_list]
df['in_series'] = b.str.contains(a, regex=False)
```

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: JohanC Thank you! Was about to rephrase my question but that answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

One of the few cases we can use `apply` to check presence of `id` in `id_list`:

```
df['in_series'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['id']) in ', '.join(str(y) for y in x['id_list']),axis=1)

   id             id_list  in_series
0  23  [1, 2, 34, 56, 75]      False
1  14  [1, 5, 14, 23, 45]       True
2   2   [1, 2, 4, 25, 37]       True
3  14  [2, 4, 34, 26, 77]      False
4  27  [1, 6, 19, 27, 50]       True
```

Answer (score 1):

you still can use a loop

```
id_list=[[1,2,34,56,75],[1,5,14,23,45],[1,2,4,25,37],[2,4,34,26,77],[1,6,19,27,50]]
id=[23,14,2,14,27]
df=pd.DataFrame([id,id_list]).T
df.columns=["id","id_list"]

boo=list()
for i in range(len(df)):
    boo.append(df.iloc[i,0] in df.iloc[i,1])

df["in_series (desired return column]"]=boo
```

in this case you don't change the type of your data

Answer (score 0):

a little list comprehension magic should work :

```
df['in_series (desired return column'] = ([df.id[i].astype(str) in df.id_list[i] 
                                          for i in range(len(df))])



   print(df)
        index   id  id_list in_series (desired return column)
0   1   23  [1,2,34,56,75]  False
1   2   14  [1,5,14,23,45]  True
2   3   2   [1,2,4,25,37]   True
3   4   14  [2,4,34,26,77]  False
4   5   27  [1,6,19,27,50]  True
```